# There are not available platforms

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Im using cocos2d-x version 12 and NDKrc12 and I have all the paths in my 
.bash_profile set. But when I build for android and type:

cocos compile -p android

It displays a message "There are not available platforms" which can't be because I have the android SDK installed in the correct path what is wrong?

Comment: Version 3.12 is better to use NDK 11c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the latest version of cocos2d-x for some odd reason you need to use the '-s' option like this:
cocos run -s /Users/me/myprojects/mygame -p android

Otherwise without '-s' it displays "there are not available platforms"
seems unnecessary when your in your project folder but I guess it is!

Comment: This should only be necessary if you're running `cocos compile|run` from somewhere other than the project's root directory, which is the directory containing the .cocos-project.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Run `android` on the command line, this will open the Android SDK manager. From here make sure that you have installed the appropriate SDK for your device.

Answer (score 0):

cd your project root, then open .cocos_project.json, find "android_cfg" arg, if you have the folder. if you don't find, then create a new cocos project, cocos compile, then judge which platform can run, in new project folder open .cocos_project.json. You can look for diffences between them.